# Is CROSS APPLY the best way or possibly WHEN EXISTS or a subquery?

Tags: t-sql, subquery, exists, cross-apply

I am relatively inexperienced when it comes to SQL. I an wondering if using `CROSS APPLY` is the best option in the SQL below?

I also think I am duplicating work. This works and takes a few minutes but my feeling is it can be done better.

The three main tables I'm looking at are quite large and on their own we are looking at a couple of million rows each. The individual insert statements are pulling back around 7-15K rows each.

---

```
DECLARE @Master TABLE
  (
     heyno              NVARCHAR(12),
     postcodestartdttm  DATE,
     postcodeenddttm    DATE,
     lzohistorypostcode NVARCHAR(25),
     biactivitypostcode NVARCHAR(25),
     activityenddttm    DATE
  );

INSERT INTO @Master
SELECT p.pasid,
       par.startdttm,
       par.enddttm,
       pa.postcode AS LZOHistoryPostcode,
       t.postcode  AS BIActivityPostcode,
       t.admitdate
FROM   HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddressrole] AS par
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddress] AS pa
               ON par.[addressoid] = pa.[oid]
                  AND pa.[status] = 'A'
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.lzo_patient AS p
               ON par.identifyingoid = p.oid
       --- 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT i.admitdate,
                           i.postcode
                    FROM   HEALTHBI_VIEWS.DBO.ip_admission i
                    WHERE  i.patientoid = p.oid
                           AND i.admitdate > par.startdttm
                           AND i.admitdate >= '01 APRIL 2010'
                           AND i.admitdate < ISNULL(par.enddttm, '31-dec-4712')
                           AND par.[status] = 'A'
                           AND par.[identifyingtype] = 'Patient'
                           AND par.[rotypcode] = 'CC_USUALADD'
                           AND pa.[adtypcode] = 'Address'
                           AND pa.postcode <> i.postcode) AS t

INSERT INTO @Master
SELECT p.pasid,
       par.startdttm,
       par.enddttm,
       pa.postcode AS LZOHistoryPostcode,
       t.postcode  AS BIActivityPostcode,
       t.apptstartdate
FROM   HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddressrole] AS par
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddress] AS pa
               ON par.[addressoid] = pa.[oid]
                  AND pa.[status] = 'A'
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.lzo_patient AS p
               ON par.identifyingoid = p.oid
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT i.apptstartdate,
                           i.postcode
                    FROM   HEALTHBI_VIEWS.DBO.op_appointment i
                    WHERE  i.patientoid = p.oid
                           AND i.apptstartdate > par.startdttm
                           AND i.apptstartdate >= '01 APRIL 2010'
                           AND i.apptstartdate < ISNULL(par.enddttm, '31-dec-4712')
                           AND par.[status] = 'A'
                           AND par.[identifyingtype] = 'Patient'
                           AND par.[rotypcode] = 'CC_USUALADD'
                           AND pa.[adtypcode] = 'Address'
                           AND pa.postcode <> i.postcode) AS t

INSERT INTO @Master
SELECT p.pasid,
       par.startdttm,
       par.enddttm,
       pa.postcode AS LZOHistoryPostcode,
       t.postcode  AS BIActivityPostcode,
       t.attenddate
FROM   HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddressrole] AS par
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddress] AS pa
               ON par.[addressoid] = pa.[oid]
                  AND pa.[status] = 'A'
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.lzo_patient AS p
               ON par.identifyingoid = p.oid
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT i.attenddate,
                           i.postcode
                    FROM   HEALTHBI_VIEWS.DBO.ed_attendance i
                    WHERE  i.patientoid = p.oid
                           AND i.attenddate > par.startdttm
                           AND i.attenddate >= '01 APRIL 2010'
                           AND i.attenddate < ISNULL(par.enddttm, '31-dec-4712')
                           AND par.[status] = 'A'
                           AND par.[identifyingtype] = 'Patient'
                           AND par.[rotypcode] = 'CC_USUALADD'
                           AND pa.[adtypcode] = 'Address'
                           AND pa.postcode <> i.postcode) AS t

SELECT m.heyno,
       m.lzohistorypostcode,
       m.biactivitypostcode,
       d.startofweek
FROM   @Master m
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI_VIEWS.DBO.date_reference AS d
               ON m.activityenddttm = d.datevalue
GROUP  BY m.heyno,
          m.lzohistorypostcode,
          m.biactivitypostcode,
          d.startofweek
ORDER  BY m.heyno
```

Comment: Why not `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: because the main joins are 1-1 against PK.

Comment: So? What does that matter?

Comment: Cross apply is like inner join with the difference that it can also be used with subqueries and table valued functions. It's not slow. In this case you could achive the same result with join with clearer code. The reason for slowness is somewhere else than cross apply.

Answer (score -1):

You do not want to use CROSS APPLY. This is meant to be used with table value functions and it works a little bit like a cursor, one record at a time, which is much slower than set operations.

I would try to use an OUTER JOIN instead like below. It's hard to get it right without understanding the data better, but it seems that for each patient you will get multiple admission dates and post codes, so you may have some duplication depending on what ip_addmission view returns. If that is not desired, you can look into using GROUP BY to return only the latest admission date for example.

Also, avoid using functions in WHERE clause as they can cause a table scan. I replaced ISNULL with an OR expression below.

```
SELECT p.pasid,
       par.startdttm,
       par.enddttm,
       pa.postcode AS LZOHistoryPostcode,
       i.postcode  AS BIActivityPostcode,
       i.admitdate
FROM   HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddressrole] AS par
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.[lzo_patientaddress] AS pa
               ON par.[addressoid] = pa.[oid]
                  AND pa.[status] = 'A'
       INNER JOIN HEALTHBI.DBO.lzo_patient AS p
               ON par.identifyingoid = p.oid
       --- 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN HEALTHBI_VIEWS.DBO.ip_admission i
        ON i.patientoid = p.oid

WHERE  i.admitdate > par.startdttm
                           AND i.admitdate >= '01 APRIL 2010'
                           AND (i.admitdate < par.enddttm OR par.enddttm IS NULL)
                           AND par.[status] = 'A'
                           AND par.[identifyingtype] = 'Patient'
                           AND par.[rotypcode] = 'CC_USUALADD'
                           AND pa.[adtypcode] = 'Address'
                           AND pa.postcode <> i.postcode;
```

Comment: You are wrong about this: "Cross apply is meant to be used with table value functions and it works a little bit like a cursor, one record at a time, which is much slower than set operations." APPLY works as fast as JOIN.